# Looping workflow across attribute table using Google Earth Engine

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, ndvi

I have a shapefile asset loaded with an attribute column called "OBJECTID". I would like to run the following script for every ID number in the attribute table, and produce an output table.

```js
/// define a geometry called Geometry.

//visualize the area you are working with
Map.addLayer(geometry)

// Landat 5 surface reflection data
var L5coll = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_TOA")
//Filter the cloud cover 
.filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER',40))
//select the desired NIR and R bands
.select(['B3', 'B4'])
//use only the geometry specified
.filterBounds(geometry)

// Landat 7 surface reflection data, fill in the gaps! See USGS pages for more info
var L7coll = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_TOA")
//filter the cloud cover
.filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER',40))
//select the NIR and R bands
.select(['B3', 'B4'])
//Use geometry specified
.filterBounds(geometry)
//creaate a variable that takes the focal mean of the pixels surrounding the missing gaps of L7 imagery
//the variable is then used to return a blended image which contains filled in gaps using .blend func.
.map(function(image){
  var filled1a = image.focal_mean(2, 'square', 'pixels', 1)
  // fills in gaps via blending 
  return filled1a.blend(image);
})

// Landat 8 surface reflection data, rename the band names. See USGS pages for more info
var L8coll = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA")
//filter for cloud cover
.filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER',40))
//use desired geometry
.filterBounds(geometry)
//applies the function over the image collection
.map(function(image){
  //renames the bands to match previous landsat imagery
  return image.rename(['B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7', 'B8', 'B9', 'B10', 'B11']);
})
//select NIR and R bands, now renamed to match L5 and L7 imagery
.select(['B3', 'B4']);

// merge L5, L7 & L8
var collection_merge = ee.ImageCollection(L5coll.merge(L7coll.merge(L8coll)));
print (collection_merge)
// add NDVI 
var addNDVI = function(image) {
  //GEE has a normalized difference function built in
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B4', 'B3']).rename('NDVI');
  return image.addBands(ndvi);
};
// create image collection from merged landsat imagery, filter boundaries and dates, select bands
var collection1 = collection_merge
//filters based on AOI
    .filterBounds(geometry)
    //Filters the input dates
    .filterDate('2000-01-01', '2017-12-31')
    //selects NIR and R bands
    .select(['B3', 'B4'])
    //applies NDVI to image collection merge
    .map(addNDVI).select('NDVI');

//Calculating annual NDVI
    var year = ee.List.sequence(2009,2017);
    var year_func = function(y){
      var range = ee.Filter.calendarRange (y, y, 'year');
      return collection1.select('NDVI').filter(range).mean().set ('Year', y)
    };
    var yearwise_ndvi = ee.ImageCollection(year.map(year_func));
    print (yearwise_ndvi);
    Map.addLayer (yearwise_ndvi)

//Creating time-series chart:
var chart = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion ({
  imageCollection: yearwise_ndvi,
  regions: geometry,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 30,
  xProperty: 'Year'
}).setChartType('ScatterChart')
  .setOptions ({title: "Median NDVI 2009 - 2017",
  hAxis: {title: 'Year', format: 'year'}
});

// chart the NDVI time series
//chart by region uses input geometry and yearwise_ndvi
//ee.Reducer.median is taking the median NDVI for each tile charted

print(chart)
//export the time series as a table via console
//in the console the table can be exported from the chart
var projectyear = 2000
var startyear = projectyear - 1
var endyear = projectyear + 1

// Run the loop
for (var yr= projectyear; yr <= endyear; yr = yr + 1) {

  print('This is year ' + yr)
  print(yr)
}
```